# How can I treat the output of a command as a file?

Tags: bash, sh

The `whiptail` command has an option `--textbox` that has the following description:

```
--textbox <file> <height> <width>
```

The first option requires a file as input; I would like to use the output of a command in its place. It seems like this should be possible in bash - possibly with redirection? For the sake of the question, let's say I'd like to view the output of `ls -l` in a whiptail textbox.

### Update

It looks like the marked answer does answer the question I asked, just not as regards to whiptail. For example, `cat <(ls -l)` works. Hence I will mark the question as answered, even though the specific example of whiptail does not work with process substitution.

Comment: I've created [another stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23089988/118234) to specifically address whiptail, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this **process substitution** syntax:

```
--textbox <(command) 600 800
```

Replace `command` with your custom command.

Comment: This looks right, and whiptail runs - but it displays an empty textbox for me. Any ideas why?

Comment: @JoBu1324 Are you sure you are running bash as your shell?

Comment: I just tried it with bash version 4.1.5 and 4.2.45 - same difference.

Comment: Still doesn't work with whiptail, although I'm marking the question as answered (because it is).

Comment: I think I know why process substitution doesn't work with whiptail's `--textbox` option - the "files" created aren't seekable. `--textbox` allows navigation.

Answer (score -1):

Does this meet your needs?

`ls -l > my_file
whiptail --textbox my_file`

Comment: Actually, that's what I was specifically trying to avoid! Thanks, though.

Comment: Ha, oh well.  Hopefully the other answers are a better fit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Rico, sorry, I think I was overreacting... I'll delete my comment and we can just pretend it never happend ok :)