# How to display command output in a whiptail textbox

Tags: bash, sh, whiptail

The `whiptail` command has an option `--textbox` that has the following description:

```
--textbox <file> <height> <width>
```

The first option requires a file as input; I would like to use the output of a command in its place. It seems like this should be possible in sh or bash. For the sake of the question, let's say I'd like to view the output of `ls -l` in a whiptail textbox.

Note that process substitution does not appear to work in whiptail (e.g. whiptail --textbox <(ls -l) 40 80 does *not* work.

This question is a re-asking of [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23089426/118234), which technically was answered.

Comment: I have a guess as to why process substitution does not work; the "files" created are not seekable, and `--textbox` allows file naviation (up/down...).

Comment: If JoBu1324's hunch is correct (it sounds reasonable to me), then there's always temp files: `t=$(mktemp); ls -l > $t; whiptail --textbox $t 40 80`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, the question says that

```
whiptail --textbox <(ls -l) 40 80
```

"doesn't work". It's most certainly worth stating clearly that the nature of the failure is that whiptail displays an empty textbox. (That's mentioned in a comment to an answer to the original question, linked in this question, but that's a pretty obscure place to look for a problem report.)

In 2014, this workaround was available (and was the original contents of this answer):

```bash
whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 40 80 <<<"$(ls -l)"
```

That will still work in 2022, if `ls -l` produces enough output (at least 64k on a standard Linux/Bash install).

Another possible workaround is to use a msgbox instead of a textbox:

```bash
whiptail --msgbox "$(ls -l)" 40 80
```

However, that will fail if the output from the command is too large to use as a command-line argument, which might be the case at 128k.

So if you can guess reasonably accurately how big the output will be, one of those solutions will work. Up to around 100k, you can use the msgbox solution; beyond that, you can use the textbox with a here-string.

But that's far from ideal, since it's really hard to reliably guess the size of the output of a command, even within a factor of two.
What will always work is to save the output of the command to a temporary file, then provide the file to whiptail, and then delete the file. (In fact, you can delete the file immediately, since Posix systems don't delete files until there are no open file handles.) But no matter how hard you try, you will occasionally end up with a file which should have been deleted. On Linux, your best bet is to create temporary files in the `/tmp` directory, which is an in-memory filesystem which is emptied automatically on reboot.

#### Why does this happen?

I came up with the solution above, eight years prior to this edit, on the assumption that OP was correct in their guess that the problem had to do with not being able to `seek()` a process substituted fd. Indeed, it's true that you can't `seek()` `/dev/fd/63`. It was also true at the time that bash implemented here-strings and here-docs by creating a temporary file to hold the expanded text, and then redirecting standard input (or whatever fd was specified) to that temporary file. So the suggested workaround did work; it ensured that `/dev/stdin` was just a regular file.

But in 2022, [the same question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73724270/1566221), this time because the suggested workaround failed. As it turns out, the reason is that Bash v5.1, which was released in late 2020, attempts to optimise small here-strings and here-docs:

> c. Here documents and here strings now use pipes for the expanded document if it's smaller than the pipe buffer size, reverting to temporary files if it's larger.
>
> *(from the Bash `CHANGES` file; changes between bash 5.1alpha and bash 5.0, in section 3, New features in Bash.)*

So with the new Bash version, unless the here-string is bigger than a pipe buffer (on Linux, 16 pages), it will no longer be a regular file.

One slightly confusing aspect of this issue is that whiptail does not, in fact, try to call `lseek()` on the textbox file. So the initial guess about the nature of the problem was not exact. That's not all that surprising, since using `lseek()` on a FIFO to position the stream at `SEEK_END` produces an explicit error, and it's reasonable to expect software to actually report error returns. But whiptail does not attempt to get the filesize by seeking to the end. Instead, it `fstat()`s the file and gets the file size from the `st_size` field in the returned `struct stat`. It then allocates exactly enough memory to hold the contents of the file, and reads the indicated number of bytes.

Of course, `fstat` cannot report the size of a FIFO, since that's not known until the FIFO is completely drained. But unlike `lseek`, that's not considered an error. `fstat` is documented as not filling in the `st_size` field on FIFOs, sockets, character devices, and other stream types. As it happens, on Linux the `st_size` field is filled in as 0 for such file descriptors, but Posix actually allows it to be unset. In any case, there is no error indication, and it's essentially impossible to distinguish between a stream which doesn't have a known size and a stream which is known to have size 0, like an empty file. Thus, whiptail treats a FIFO as though it were an empty file, reading 0 bytes and presenting an empty textbox.

#### What about dialog?

One alternative to whiptail is [Dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/), currently maintained by Thomas Dickey. You can often directly substitute dialog for whiptail, and it has some additional widgets which can be useful. However, it does not provide a simple solution in this case.

Unlike whiptail, dialog's textbox attempts to avoid reading the entire file into memory before drawing the widget. As a result, it does depend on `lseek()` in order to read out of order, and thus cannot work on special files at all. Attempting to use a FIFO with dialog produces an error message, rather than drawing an empty textbox; that makes diagnosis easier but doesn't really solve the underlying problem. Dialog does have a variety of widgets which can read from `stdin`, but as far as I know none of them allow scrolling, so they're only useful if the command output fits in a single window. But it's possible that I've missed something.

#### Drawing out a moral: just read until you reach the end

(Skip this section if you're only interested in using command-line utilities, not writing them.)

The tragic part of this complicated tale is that it was all completely unnecessary. Whiptail is going to read the entire file in any case; trying to get the size of the file before reading was either laziness or a misguided attempt to optimise. Had the code just read until an end of file indication, possibly allocating more memory as needed, all these problems would have been avoided. And not just these problems. As it happens, Posix does not guarantee that the `st_size` field is accurate even for apparently normal files. Stat is only required to report accurate sizes for symlinks (the length of the link itself) and shared memory objects. The Linux documentation indicates that `st_size` will be returned as 0 for certain automatically-generated files:

> For  example,  the value 0 is returned for many files under the `/proc` directory, while various files under `/sys` report a size of 4096 bytes, even though the file content is smaller.  For such files, one should simply try to read as many bytes as  possible (and append '\0' to the returned buffer if it is to be interpreted as a string). *(from `man 7 inode`)*.

`lseek` will also fail on many autogenerated files, as well as sockets, FIFOs and character devices. So the more common idiom for this particular optimization is also unreliable, as well as leading to TOCTOU-like race conditions when the file is truncated or appended to while it is being read.

Comment: Where does /dev/stdin fit in? That isn't a regular file. Nice solution, btw!

Comment: That's just a Bashist roundabout way of saying `ls -l | whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 40 80`

Comment: @tripleee: But the two expressions are behaviourally distinguishable. Mine is implemented with a (seekable) temporary file; yours is implemented with a (non-seekable) unix socket. TIAS.

Comment: @JoBu1324: /dev/stdin links to whatever stdin has been redirected to. If it has been redirected to a regular file, then it resolves to a regular file. You could also use `/dev/fd/0`.

Comment: So it sounds like `<<<` links `/dev/stdin` to a temporary file. Is that a correct way of thinking about it? I suddenly think there is a lot about stdin I don't know.

Comment: @JoBu1324: Yes, that's what I said in the answer, no? If you do `cmd </path/to/foo` then `stdin` is just `/path/to/foo` (i.e. as regular a file as `foo` is).

Comment: @rici Thanks for clarifying. I didn't catch that because I've never thought about the nature of `/dev/stdin` before.