# (Bash) How do I display a command output in a whiptail textbox?

Tags: bash, whiptail

The [whiptail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail) command has a `--textbox` option

> A **text** box lets you display the contents of a text file in a dialog box

I would like to use the output of a command in its place (yup, that's the same question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089988/how-to-display-command-output-in-a-whiptail-textbox)), but the difference is that when I run the command [in the response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23091156) (not the same) `whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 30 60 <<< "$(echo Hello)"` I get an empty textbox [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJS61.png).

Which other ways could you handle the output of a command as a file?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem, but `<<< "$(echo Hello)"` is convoluted.  Why not just `<<<"Hello"`?.  If you want to pass the output of a command (eg `echo`) to whiptail, use a `|` eg `echo Hello | whiptail ... `.  I use `/dev/stdin` this way regularly so I'm not sure why your example doesn't work

Comment: Yeah that's weird, with `whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 30 60 <<<"Hello"` I got [an empty textbox](https://i.imgur.com/R6IpM1P.png) and `echo Hello | whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 30 60` [the same result](https://i.imgur.com/wQIfX8o.png)

Comment: if any one of those variations doesn't work, it makes sense that other equivalents wouldn't work too.  does it work with a regular file?

Comment: It works for me, just like it did in that question. Could you perhaps reveal which version of whiptail you're using (should be available from `whiptail --version`) and on what operating system and shell?

Comment: What O/S are you using?  I cannot reproduce on ubuntu 20.04.   All of the following produce at text box with "foo bar" in it:  `$ whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 25 50 <<<"$(echo foo bar)"` or `$ whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 25 50 <<<"foo bar"` or  `whiptail --textbox foo.txt 25 50` or `whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 25 50 <foo.txt`

Comment: @DanielFarrell Yes it works with regular files. E.g. "File" file that simply says "Hello, I'm a file!" [as you can see here](https://i.imgur.com/DDIe46V.png)

Comment: @j_b: Ubuntu 20.04 still uses bash v5.0; this particular symptom appears with bash v5.1, for reasons analysed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23091156/1566221). (I only just figured all this out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `cmd | whiptail --textbox /dev/stdin 30 60` doesn't work for you because you're using Bash v5.1, not because of any changes in whiptail.

You can still use this alternative workaround:

```bash
whiptail --scrolltext --msgbox "$(cmd)" 30 60
```

provided the output of `cmd` is not too big to include in the command line (around 128kb).

I rewrote the [original question which you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23091156/1566221), taking into account the change in Bash v5.1 and a more accurate analysis of the original problem, so I'm not going to repeat all of that here.

Comment: Weird, I'm using bash... But thank you! Your command [worked like a charm](https://i.imgur.com/L6WvV5I.png). I used `whiptail --msgbox "$(echo $MESSAGE | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')" $(stty size)` as an example

Comment: @IwakuraLain: I'm glad you got it working, but I'm still curious. Which version of `whiptail` have you got? And what OS do you use? (Eg. Ubuntu Linux 20.04, macOS 12.0, ...)

Comment: I'm also curious which version `whiptail` and where came from

Comment: ```whiptail (newt): 0.52.21``` and I'm using Fedora 36

Comment: I made a post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/xe7ngc/how_do_i_display_a_command_output_in_a_whiptail/iogt8en/) about the same thing and someone also had a similar situation because of the version but in Debian

Comment: Maybe it's a bug or bad luck

Comment: @IwakuraLain: I guess it could be described as bad luck :-( I tracked it down to a version change, but not in whiptail; it's a version change in bash. I'm writing it all up now.